# Convergence of Sequences of Functions Evaluated at Sequences in Their Domain

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation, sequence-of-function

Suppose

(1) A sequence of continuous functions$f_n(x)$ converges to a continuous function $f(x)$ pointwise on some set $I$, and

(2) a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x \in I$

(****) Is it true that $f_n(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$? (****)

The way I try and break it down is to say that:

$|f_n(x_n) - f(x)| \le |f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)| + |f(x_n)-f(x)|$

The second term can be made arbitrarily small since $f$ is continuous (For $\epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta$ such that $|x_n-x| < \delta \implies |f(x_n)-f(x)| < \epsilon/2$), and this holds for all $n$ large enough because of the convergence of the $x_n$ to $x$.

However, I have no idea how to bound the first term without making the assumption of uniform convergence.  My question (****) comes from the idea that if I create two indexes ($f_n(x_m)$) and let $n \rightarrow \infty$, I get that $f_n(x_m) \rightarrow f(x_m)$ and subsequently let $m \rightarrow \infty$, it converges to $f(x)$.

If I take the limit of the $x_m$ followed by the limit of the $f_n(x)$, it once again converges to $f(x)$, so it would make sense for my answer to (****) to be yes, but I can't prove it.  A counterexample would be helpful if it's false.  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. In fact this property is equivalent to uniform convergence. So it is easy to give counterexamples. On $[0,1]$ we can construct a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ such that $f_n(x)=0$ for $x >\frac 1 n$, $f_n(0)=0$ and $f_n(\frac 1 {2n})=1$. [Think graphically]. Then $f_n \to 0$ pointwise and $\frac 1 {2n} \to 0$ but $f_n(\frac 1 {2n})=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: In your example, $I = [0,1)$ but $x = 1 \not\in I$.  If we were to make an extension of your set to $[0,1]$, then $f$ would not be continuous.  Hence not a counterexample to the conditions I've provided, right?

Comment: @RichardGroenewald I was very careless with the example. I have corrected it. If needed I can write down the definition of $f_n$ explicitly but if you think in terms of the graphs you can see what type of functions I am considering.